# Compiler Error on use declared public variables in other forms

Tags: delphi, variables, public, delphi-xe3

I declare many public variable ago but in Delphi-XE3 is in first.

i declare public var good but can't use it on other forms but i don't know why ?

my main unite code :

```
unit uMian;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ComCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    btnLoad: TButton;
    btnShow: TButton;
    btnEaxit: TButton;
    lvStudent: TListView;
    btnAdd: TButton;
    procedure btnEaxitClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnLoadClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
    procedure btnAddClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations } 
  var
    IsOpen : Boolean ;

  public
    { Public declarations }
    var
      myvar : Integer ;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses uAdd;


function AppDir () : string ;
begin
  Result := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName);
end;

procedure TForm1.btnAddClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if IsOpen then
  frmAdd.ShowModal ;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnEaxitClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  close;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  if IsOpen then
  //CloseFile(DataFile);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IsOpen := False ;
end;

....

end.
```

This is work good without problem.

But when i use on other form FrmAdd i have problem:

```
unit uAdd;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.Buttons,
  Vcl.Samples.Spin, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TfrmAdd = class(TForm)
    lbledtName: TLabeledEdit;
    lbledtAvg: TLabeledEdit;
    seAge: TSpinEdit;
    lbleId: TLabeledEdit;
    btnCansek: TBitBtn;
    btnAdd: TBitBtn;
    procedure btnAddClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  frmAdd: TfrmAdd;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses uMian;

procedure TfrmAdd.btnAddClick(Sender: TObject);

begin
  // problem in below 
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(TForm1.myvar)) ;
end;

end.
```

Compiler error :
[dcc32 Error] uAdd.pas(problem line): E2096 Method identifier expected

The note : Cnpack show me `myvar` in variables list but Rad Studio Auto-Complete not.

Comment: depending on your intention to use a instaced variable or a class variable you will have to change your declaration :    Class var myvar:integer; or your call to Instance.myvar

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`myvar` is a public variable of an object, that is, an *instance* of class `TForm1`. Hence, you need to specify *what* instance you are referring to. But when you write `TForm1.myvar`, you don't specify any instance, only the class.

It's like knowing that each human has a property known as "sex", and then you ask, "What is the sex of a human?". [*Which* human?]

The solution is to write `someform.myvar` instead, where `someform` is an instance of a `TForm1`. For instance, `Form1.myvar`, is most likely what you want. Notice that you find `var Form1: TForm1` in `uMain`. This is the line where the form variable is declared: You got a variable pointing to an object of class `TForm1`.

So, instead, you ask, "What is the sex of your your friend Smith?"

Comment: Oh Thank you form your Answer :)

Comment: +1 for "sex", because of course, eye-color and height are boring. And if I had to guess, Smith is a brown eyed, 175 cm *male*.